# Varying Coefficient model conditioned on a coded and continuous variable

Tags: r, regression, statsmodels

Hello I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have a hypothesis that a simple linear model 
($Y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X + \varepsilon$) is insufficient to capture some dynamics of the contemporaneous relationship between Y and X.

Instead the following varying coefficient model is deemed a more appropriate description of the relationship :

$ Y = \beta_{0}(X,S) + \beta_1(X,S) X + \varepsilon $

where $\beta_{i}$'s are functions of $(X,S)$

X is a one dimensional continuous random variable.

S is a categorical variable coded as {0,1}. In the current data set that I have, $S_{i}$ is the quantile rank of each $X_{i}$ currently. But in the future, it might be a smooth function of X.

Thus far, I have tried to do the following:

$ Y = (\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} X) + (\beta_{2} + \beta_{3} X)\mathbb{1}[X \in Q] + \varepsilon$

where Q is the prescribed quantile. I am able to obtain some numbers but I am not sure that such a simplification is enough to capture the dynamics at hand.

I was wondering if there are any resources in python (preferably) or R to estimate this equation given historical data which is a list of observations $ (Y_{i},X_{i},S_{i}) $

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: If you make two separate scatterplots of the data for the two categories of 0 and 1, in both scatterplots the data should appear to approximately lie on some straight or curved line. If this is not the case in this instance, I don't think  combining the data together would be easily modeled.

Comment: @JamesPhillips...All I have is $(Y_{i} , X_{i})$ of data where both of them are continuous. I am trying a hypothesis that an augmented linear model as shown above provides a more interesting fit and hopefully some kind of causal interpretation. S is actually generated from $X_{i}$ ...e.g.S is the Quantile Rank of $X_{i} $ based on a proposed distribution.

Comment: @JamesPhillips.. The data I have is IP protected and is the property of the firm I work for. But any continuous data will suffice.

Comment: My apology. When I read in the question "[the data] is a list of observations (Yi,Xi,Si)" I wrongly thought that meant "[the data] is a list of observations (Yi,Xi,Si)". It is my misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you attempting to estimate the $\beta_i$ or have you specified them as functions of $X$ and $S$?  Indeed, what is your objective: to fit such a model or, as suggested at the outset, to assess how well the simpler model works?

Comment: My objective is to understand how $ \beta_{i} $ varies per each level of the Binary variable S. The inclusion of X in to the function specification of $ \beta_{i} $ attempt to see if the deviation is more pronounced for large values of X. As a statement, I am more or less an advanced beginner w.r.t statistical modelling. Please condone my lack of appropriate terminology.